# Do variables retain values on orientation change?

Tags: android

I know that when you change the device from landscape to portrait and vice versa, the `onCreate` method is called. That has been a cause of some problems for me.

Say I have a database which holds the downloads that are to be performed. I plan on making a splash screen where a DAO object will convert this data into objects and put them into a `Vector<DownloadTask>`. This will happen on an `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()`.
`onPostExecute` the splash screen will start a new `Activity`.

All is fine so far except when I have to handle orientation change.
The new Acitivity after the splash screen will start a `Timer` which is responsible for scheduling the downloads. This will be started in `onCreate`. The `DownloadTask` all implement `Runnable` so they are threads.

When the download is over or abruptly stopped, the thread is supposed to tell this to the scheduler and decrease the number of threads running simultaneously. This is to cap the number of simultaneous downloads.

So, if the timing is right (or wrong) such that the orientation change and the fninishing of the thread line up together, **what will happen to the Timer ?** Will it be null ?

*When orientation changes, are the variables reset to their default value ?*
Also, how do I prevent orientation change ?? Like some games do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When orientation changes, are the variables reset to their default value ?

If they are `Activity` level variables then yes they will return to their default values since the `Activity` is destroyed and recreated each time. To avoid this you could either save the variables in `finish()` each time but this could be messy since you don't know when this might happen (but there are ways around that). You could also specify in your `manifest.xml` that you will handle these changes by adding

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to your `<activity>` tags in the `manifest`. In the docs, they don't recommend this but I think mostly to cover their butts. I do it and haven't had any problems so far. This will keep the `Activity` from being destroyed.

> Also, how do I prevent orientation change ??

You can do this also in the `manifest` by adding something like

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

to the `<activity>` tag for those `Activities` that you wish to have a certain `orientation`.

Comment: I was going over the docs, too, and I guess that `onDestroy()` is called when orientation change occurs. I must save the data back to the database, I believe :) is `onStop` supposed to be quick ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "quick" but note the docs about `onDestroy()`, "Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! "

Comment: then where do I save the data back to the db ??

Comment: `onPause()` or `onStop()` would be safer. Or, as I suggested, specify in the `manifest` to handle orientation changes yourself

Comment: Since 3.0 android has introduced Loaders which can take care of these kind of scenarios in a better way compared to AsyncTask. have a look at it : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html